# Show two fields from two tables as one field in mysql LIKE

Tags: mysql, select, sql-like

I want to implement like search for autocomplete.I have two tables,Location and SubLocation.

I want to return only one field for this like.Here is my query

```
SELECT l.loc_name,sl.sub_loc FROM Location l,SubLocation sl 
 where l.loc_name LIKE '$term%' OR sl.sub_loc='$term%'
```

I want to show matching result from both tables as one return.EG,if i type D so i can view Dubai from first table and DubaiMarina from second table as one coloumn

Comment: No..i do not need to concatenate it...

Comment: I want to do it for autocomplete...i want to suggest user his location or sublocation while they type anything

Comment: but why 'Marina' for D?

Comment: see it now..it was Dubai Marina..sory for mis typing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNION`

```
SELECT l.loc_name FROM Location l
 where l.loc_name LIKE '$term%' 
UNION
SELECT sl.sub_loc FROM SubLocation sl 
 where sl.sub_loc='$term%'
```

If the tables do not have duplicates, you can replace `UNION` with `UNION ALL` as the union all option will not look for duplicates, it might be a little faster depending on the amount of data in returned by the queries.

Comment: UNION is too expensive and time taken to search too many records

Comment: @Methew: You can also use [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) if this is slow for you.

Comment: How about using `UNION ALL`?

Comment: @Methew could you please how Union is expensive? Are you missing any information in the question?

Comment: Depends on the options you have. if you have more than one query giving you the same result, then you can look at performance.

Comment: `UNION` will combine recordsets and then eliminate duplicates. If the OP is union-ing thousands of duplicate records, it will be more expensive than `UNION ALL`. Union all will combine records and return it without eliminating duplicates.